# grunt requirejs multitask and multiple files

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs, grunt-requirejs

I'm using the following method to optimize multiple modules ([optimizing multiple](http://clintconklin.com/optimizing-multiple-javascript-files-with-grunt-and-requirejs/)) and everything works fine when I am not using the multitask configuration.

This works:

```
'requirejs': require('./build_config/requirejs.js')(grunt, config)
```

This doesn't:

```
'requirejs': {
'task1': require('./build_config/requirejs.js')(grunt, config)
```

}

where requirejs.js is as follows:
[The gist](https://gist.github.com/Roballen/a063956408c7e7211491)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based off the "options['task' + x]" reference it looks like you're putting your tasks inside the task1 task def which doesn't work. if you want to run all your requirejs tasks then you can just run "grunt requirejs". if you want to combine static and dynamically defined config then you could...

```
var requirejsTasks = { ... }
_.extend( requirejsTasks, require('./build_config/requirejs.js')(grunt, config) );
```

Comment: ah, I think you changed my perspective.  Gonna give this a shot.

Comment: I didn't exactly do it this way.  I ended up modifying the object inside of the ./build_config/requirejs.js which is basically the same idea.  The key here was making me realize that I was nesting tasks at the wrong level basically.